# SAML request signature verification c#

Tags: request, x509certificate, saml, signature, verification

I am creating a SAML Identity provider, and our service provider is using a third party tool Component Space to do their end's work. Identity provider I developed takes login credentials from a user and validates that user on our active directory federation server. If the user is valid then I create an SAMLResponse, sign it with X509Certificate and post it to AssertionConsumerServiceURL which I received from SAMLRequest. Now I need to verify that the SAMLRequest is coming from a valid service provider and has not be modified in between.

Initially the service provider was using HTTP redirect binding and sending the SAMLRequest, SigAlg and Signature in query string, I tried below code to verify the signature, but it always returns false.

```
public bool VerifyHashDynamic(string Signature, string request)
        {
            bool isVerified = false;

            X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath(".") + @"\X509Certificate\SP.cer", "password");
            byte[] signature = Base64DecodeArray(Signature);
            byte[] signedData = Base64DecodeArray(request);
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509.PublicKey.Key;
            SHA256Managed hash = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] hashedData;
            bool dataOK = rsaCSP.VerifyData(signedData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signature);

            hashedData = hash.ComputeHash(signedData);
            isVerified = rsaCSP.VerifyHash(hashedData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signature);

            return isVerified;
        }
```

Is there something wrong in above code, which is allowing the signature verification?

In order to make it work in another way, I asked our service provider to send AuthNRequest with embedded signature (HTTP-POST binding). For signature verification of posted AuthnRequest I tried XMLDocument verification, here is the code:

```
 public Boolean VerifyXml()
    {
        string mystr = string.Empty;

        mystr = "9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjEuMTpuYW1laWQtZm9ybWF0OnVuc3BlY2lmaWVkIiBBbGxvd0NyZWF0ZT0idHJ1ZSIgLz48L3NhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdD4=";
        mystr = GetXmlFromSAML(mystr, false);
        mystr = mystr.TrimEnd().TrimStart();
        X509Certificate2 myCert = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath(".") + @"\X509Certificate\SP.cer");
        XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
        Doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
        Doc.XmlResolver = null;
        Doc.LoadXml(mystr);

        // Check arguments.
        if (Doc == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Doc");


        // Create a new SignedXml object and pass it
        // the XML document class.
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(Doc);

        // Find the "Signature" node and create a new
        // XmlNodeList object.
        XmlNodeList nodeList = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

        // Throw an exception if no signature was found.
        if (nodeList.Count <= 0)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: No Signature was found in the document.");
        }

        // This example only supports one signature for
        // the entire XML document.  Throw an exception 
        // if more than one signature was found.
        if (nodeList.Count >= 2)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: More that one signature was found for the document.");
        }

        // Load the first <signature> node.  
        signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

        // Check the signature and return the result.
        return signedXml.CheckSignature(myCert, false);
    }
```

With above verification code I get exception "SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied". I am not sure how I can have this signature verification working.

Is it really possible to manually verify the SAMLRequest signature with X509Certificate? Is it fine to allow the login check without signature verification of AuthnRequest?

I have been googling all these for last one month, but had no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In the XmlDocument vaersion I think you want `Doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;` but that isn't causing the error.

Comment: What does the parameter `string request` look like? SAML is quite precise about including the SigAlg and the order of the parts. The way you push it into Base64DecodeArray() throws doubt on the content. It should look like `SAMLRequest=value&RelayState=value&SigAlg=value`